# How to solve for m in this equation without using the quadratic formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, calculator

> Tangents drawn from (b,a) to the hyperbola $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ makes angles $\theta_1$
> $\theta_2$ with the x-axis. If $\tan\theta_1$$\tan\theta_2$
> =2 then $b^2-a^2=....$

The equation of the tangent will be $y=mx+(a−mb)$ and since the condition of tangency is $(a-mb)^2=a^2m^2-b^2$ we get after simplify

$$m^2(b^2-a^2)-2abm+a^2+b^2=0$$

How can I find $(b^2-a^2)$ with a calculator or any easier way than the quadratic formula.

Knowing that $m_1m_2=2$

Comment: If you want to solve it on a graphing calculator then you need to know the values of $a$ and $b.$ If you do you can just graph it and use the "zero" command in the graphing calculator.

Comment: @coffeemath on a Casio 991EX or any new Casio calculator as graphing calculators aren't allowed in my exams.

Comment: What’s wrong with the quadratic formula? Unless you can factorise it at a glance, which you claim that you can’t.

Comment: It seems to me that any attempt to bypass the quadratic equation will necessarily involve either some form of factoring or some form of *completing the square*.  Both of these alternatives are very closely associated with the derivation of the quadratic equation.  Consequently, I regard this as a fool's errand.

Comment: What are $m_1, m_2$ supposed to represent?  Further, for this and your future MathSE postings, please try to make your posting so clear that it is impossible for anyone to be confused as to what you are asking.  This includes seeing if subtle ambiguities are in your (future) postings.

Comment: If all you know is that $m_1m_2=2$ (and if $m_1$ and $m_2$ are supposed to be the roots of the quadratic), then you can't find a specific value for $b^2-a^2$. By [Vieta's Formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), we know that $m_1m_2=(a^2+b^2)/(b^2-a^2)$. If $m_1m_2=2$, we can deduce $b^2=3a^2$, so that $b^2-a^2=2a^2$, but that's as far as we can go.

Comment: "Tangents drawn from (b,a) to the hyperbola...".  What hyperbola?  What is the exact equation of the hyperbola?

Comment: @Blue that answers my question it would be cool if you add this as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting a comment to an answer, as requested ...

---

If all you know is that $m_1m_2=2$ (where $m_1$ and $m_2$ are the roots of the quadratic), then you can't find a specific value for $b^2−a^2$.

By [Vieta's Formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), we know that
$$\frac{a^2+b^2}{b^2−a^2}=m_1m_2=2$$
From this, we can deduce $b^2=3a^2$, so that $b^2-a^2=2a^2$, but that's as far as we can go.